# How to set text box value in angular 4 using typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, textbox

How to set text box value in Angular 4 using TypeScript? I tried in this way but it doesn't work.

app.component.html

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <input matInput class='aaaa' placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="form1" value="{{setTextBoxValue}}">
     </mat-form-field>
  <button (click)='clickMe()'>Click Me</button>
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
}) 

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   title = 'app';
   clickMe() {
     setTextBoxValue: string = "new value";
   }
}
```

Comment: change your [(ngModel)] value make it to setTextBoxValue so that you can get you result or 
form1 : string ;
this.form1 = "your value";

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but it doesnt work either.

Comment: try luck by adding 
<input type="text" matInput class='aaaa' placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="form1" ">

Comment: Try using either [(ngModel)] or {{setTextBoxValue}}, if it works I would be interested to know why it works.

Answer (score 10):

Remove `value="{{setTextBoxValue}}"` and just use `[(ngModel)]`. For example if you have `private inputVar: string;` in your component (`.ts`) then the element would look like:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Input" [(ngModel)]="inputVar">
```

In the component (`.ts`) you could have:

```
constructor() { this.inputVar = "initial value" }
```

And then a button with `(click)` event like you have:

```
<button type="button" (click)="changeInputVar()">Test Change</button>
```

And again in your `.ts` you have the `changeInputVar()` defined:

```
private changeInputVar(): void {
  this.inputVar = "changed";
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyivtu).

Answer (score 0):

just set the model value inside the function,

```
this.fomr1 = "new value";
```

also make sure you have the form1 declared in your component,

```
form1 : string ;
```

Comment: I tried! But it doesn't work. But it gives no errors.